# Why we take lastObject for Standard Directories in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I was reading some documentation about standard directories in iOS. I checked [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html), and found this method.

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

One thing i didn't get why it's taking lastObject from NSArray and didn't found any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried to debug and find out what is in that array returned by `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)` then you might not need any explanation. This is basically returning address of your documents folder and contains only one object. By using `lastObject` or `firstObject` doesn't make any difference, you can use `firstObject` to check it yourself and might help you in understanding too.